# How to prove that $8n^3 + 12n + 3\log^3n \neq \Omega (n^4)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

How can I prove that $8n^3 + 12n + 3\log^3n \neq \Omega (n^4)$ ?
I know that $8n^3 < 8n^4$ , $12n < 12n^4$ and $3\log^3n < 3n^4$ and then I can prove that $8n^3 + 12n + 3\log^3n = O(n^4)$  but it doesn't mean that it also $\neq \Omega (n^4)$ .

How should I prove it then?

Comment: This is in fact $O(n^3)$

Comment: If I prove that it is $O(n^3)$ then it means it cannot be also $\Omega (n^4)$ ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This is why I prefer (credit to Daniel Spielman for the notation) writing

$$f(n) \leq O(n^4)$$

which makes it not contradict $$f(n) \leq O(n^3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just do the division

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{8n^3+12n+3\log^3n\over n^4}=0$$

since the limit exists, it is equal to the $\limsup$, which is exactly the proof it is not in $\Omega(n^4)$.

In your language, this means that if you assume there is $c>0$ such that $8n^3+12n+\log^3n\ge cn^4$ then this would imply

$$0< c=\lim_{n\to\infty}{cn^4\over n^4}\le \lim_{n\to\infty}{8n^3+12n+3\log^3n\over n^4}=0$$

a clear contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain? What is the lim sup? Why did you divide and calculate the limit?

Comment: What is your definition of $\Omega$? I'm using the standard Hardy-Littlewood definition as written in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation

Comment: We are using the definition that there exists $c$ and $n_{0}$ s.t $f(n) \geq c\cdot g(x)$  for all $n \geq n_{0}$ , meaning $8n^3 + 12n + 3\log^3n \geq c \cdot n^4$

Comment: @Lisa then that's the same thing, since the limit is $0$. See my edited answer.

Comment: So I get that $c$ must be equal to $0$ and that is a contradiction? I think I get it

Comment: How can you divide by $n^4$ ? Maybe it is $0$ ?

Comment: @Lisa it's the limit as $n\to\infty$ you cannot go to $\infty$ if $n$ is not much larger than $0$.